# JWPlayer Change configuration dynamically without reloading video (skin, captions, stretching)

Tags: javascript, video, greasemonkey, jwplayer

I'd like to have a Greasemonkey script to change the configuration of JWPlayer instances dynamically without reloading the video. For instance to switch the player theme, or load closed captions, etc.

I can do this with

```
var cfg = jwplayer().config;
cfg.stretching = "uniform";
jwplayer().setup(cfg);
```

but that just copies over the current configuration to a variable, alters a property then sets up a new player, and loading starts over.

I'm not sure this is possible. 
The problem I'm having is that setting up the player with the new config works ridiculously slow. It doesn't load, seeking takes a long time and there are sometimes two superimposed captions.

Comment: The player needs to be re set up in order to apply new configuration options.